# How to use curved table only using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to convert following image into a HTML with pure CSS without using any 3rd part CSS references. I have tried the following code snippet. It's code fiddle as follows,

https://jsfiddle.net/7jdmgfnx/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'>&nbsp;</p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'>Transaction Summary</p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:12px;line-height:107%;color:#AFABAB;">Amount</span></p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:11px;line-height:107%;color:#AFABAB;">LKR&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size:16px;line-height:107%;color:#0070C0;">2,000.00</span></strong></p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:12px;line-height:107%;">Commercial Bank</span></p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:12px;line-height:107%;">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <table style="width:319.5pt;margin-left:-36.25pt;border-collapse:collapse;border: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 2.25in;border: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;color:#7F7F7F;">Payment type</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 157.5pt;border-top: 1pt solid windowtext;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-left: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><strong><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;">Fund Transfer</span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 2.25in;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-left: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-top: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;color:#7F7F7F;">Paid to</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 157.5pt;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><strong><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;">1234567</span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 2.25in;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-left: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-top: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;color:#7F7F7F;">Bank</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 157.5pt;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><strong><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;">Rdb Bank</span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 2.25in;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-left: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-top: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;color:#7F7F7F;">Date of time</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 157.5pt;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><strong><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;">16-Aug-2021 11:50</span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 2.25in;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-left: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-top: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;color:#7F7F7F;">Payment Status</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 157.5pt;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><strong><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;">Success</span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 2.25in;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-left: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-top: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;color:#7F7F7F;">Reference number</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 157.5pt;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><strong><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;">32322</span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 2.25in;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-left: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-top: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;color:#7F7F7F;">Remark</span></p>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 157.5pt;border-top: none;border-left: none;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;padding: 0in 5.4pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;line-height:200%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:right;'><strong><span style="font-size:13px;line-height:200%;">Monthly bonus</span></strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="color:#2E75B6;">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="color:#2E75B6;">&nbsp;</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

But you can see, its output not the same as the following image.

1. How can I set the content to the center of the browser page as the following image.
2. How can I use the table as curved rows as the following image. (It does not have to be a table. It doesn't matter if it's something else)

please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use classes or selectors instead of repeating the same inline styling? I think what you're looking for is [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Comment: @Rafalon This is a backend requirement. I'm doing R&D to convert HTML to CSS. that library only support with inline CSS. that's why I'm used it. Can u please help me to solve this by providing complete answer

Comment: Hi, I can't understand your comment to @Rafalon - what library and what backend?

Comment: @Gamma I edited my answer to inline CSS (first it was separately). although seem it (inline CSS) is not good, your comment says that you are forced to do this work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here with table :

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
    <div style="padding: 1em; z-index: -1; background: rgb(79,206,213); background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(79,206,213,.1) 0%, rgba(20,173,227,.1) 50%, rgba(253,0,243,.1) 100%);">
      <div style="border-radius: 1em; padding: 3em 1em 1em 1em; z-index: 0; background: white;">
        <p style='margin-bottom:2em;font-size:26px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'>Transaction Summary</p>
        <p style='margin-bottom:1em;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:15px;color:#AFABAB;">Amount</span></p>
        <p style='margin-bottom:1em;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:15px;color:#AFABAB;">LKR&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size:28px;color:#0070C0;">2,000.00</span></strong></p>
        <p style='margin-bottom:2em;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:15px;font-size:18px;font-family:'Calibri',sans-serif;color:#333;">Commercial Bank</span></p>
        <table style="margin:0 auto;width:319.5pt;row-gap: .5em;margin-bottom: 2em; padding: 0 2em; font-family:'Calibri',sans-serif;font-size:15px;border-colapse:collapse;border-spacing:0 .5em">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 1em;">
              <td style="color:grey;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em; border-style:solid none;padding:.5em;border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-top-left-radius:.5em;border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;">Payment type</td>
              <td style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em;border-left:none;border-top-right-radius:.5em;border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;">Fund Transfer</td>
            </tr>
             <tr style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 1em;">
              <td style="color:grey;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em; border-style:solid none;padding:.5em;border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-top-left-radius:.5em;border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;">Paid to</td>
              <td style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em;border-left:none;border-top-right-radius:.5em;border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;">1234567r</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 1em;">
              <td style="color:grey;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em; border-style:solid none;padding:.5em;border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-top-left-radius:.5em;border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;">Bank</td>
              <td style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em;border-left:none;border-top-right-radius:.5em;border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;">Rdb Bank</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 1em;">
              <td style="color:grey;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em; border-style:solid none;padding:.5em;border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-top-left-radius:.5em;border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;">Date of time</td>
              <td style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em;border-left:none;border-top-right-radius:.5em;border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;">16-Aug-2021 11:50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 1em;">
              <td style="color:grey;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em; border-style:solid none;padding:.5em;border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-top-left-radius:.5em;border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;">Payment Status</td>
              <td style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em;border-left:none;border-top-right-radius:.5em;border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;">Success</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 1em;">
              <td style="color:grey;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em; border-style:solid none;padding:.5em;border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-top-left-radius:.5em;border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;">Reference number</td>
              <td style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em;border-left:none;border-top-right-radius:.5em;border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;">32322</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 1em;">
              <td style="color:grey;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em; border-style:solid none;padding:.5em;border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;border-top-left-radius:.5em;border-bottom-left-radius:.5em;">Remark</td>
              <td style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .5em;border-left:none;border-top-right-radius:.5em;border-bottom-right-radius:.5em;">Monthly bonus</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p style='border-top:1px solid #e3e3e3;'></p>
        <p style='font-size:12px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="color:#2E75B6;">Aug-2021 12:56 PM</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is using from multiple `div` and `flex` instead table:

```html
<html>

<body>

  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'>&nbsp;</p>
  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'>Transaction Summary</p>
  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:12px;line-height:107%;color:#AFABAB;">Amount</span></p>
  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:11px;line-height:107%;color:#AFABAB;">LKR&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size:16px;line-height:107%;color:#0070C0;">2,000.00</span></strong></p>
  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:12px;line-height:107%;">Commercial Bank</span></p>
  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:12px;line-height:107%;">&nbsp;</span></p>
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;border: 1px solid #eee;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 0.30em; padding: 10px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>Payment type</div>
    <div>Fund Transfer</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;border: 1px solid #eee;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 0.30em; padding: 10px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>Paid to</div>
    <div>1234567</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;border: 1px solid #eee;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 0.30em; padding: 10px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>Bank</div>
    <div>Rdb Bank</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;border: 1px solid #eee;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 0.30em; padding: 10px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>Date of time</div>
    <div>16-Aug-2021 11:50</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;border: 1px solid #eee;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 0.30em; padding: 10px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>Payment Status</div>
    <div>Success</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;border: 1px solid #eee;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 0.30em; padding: 10px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>Reference number</div>
    <div>32322</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;border: 1px solid #eee;display: flex;justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 0.30em; padding: 10px; border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>Remark</div>
    <div>Monthly bonus</div>
  </div>

  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="color:#2E75B6;">&nbsp;</span></p>
  <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:107%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="color:#2E75B6;">&nbsp;</span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that layout doesn't look like it need a table tag. Divs or spans would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like following snippet, with list and flex:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
    <div style="padding: 1em; z-index: -1; background: rgb(79,206,213); background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(79,206,213,.1) 0%, rgba(20,173,227,.1) 50%, rgba(253,0,243,.1) 100%);">
      <div style="border-radius: 1em; padding: 3em 1em 1em 1em; z-index: 0; background: white;">
        <p style='margin-bottom:2em;font-size:26px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'>Transaction Summary</p>
        <p style='margin-bottom:1em;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:15px;color:#AFABAB;">Amount</span></p>
        <p style='margin-bottom:1em;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:15px;color:#AFABAB;">LKR&nbsp;</span><strong><span style="font-size:28px;color:#0070C0;">2,000.00</span></strong></p>
        <p style='margin-bottom:2em;text-align:center;'><span style="font-size:15px;font-size:18px;font-family:'Calibri',sans-serif;color:#333;">Commercial Bank</span></p>
        <ul style="display: flex;flex-direction:column;list-style:none;width:319.5pt;row-gap: .5em;margin-bottom: 2em; padding: 0 2em; font-family:'Calibri',sans-serif;font-size:15px;">
          <li style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .4em; border-radius: .5em; display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;align-items:center;">
            <span style="color:grey;">Payment type</span>
            <span style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;">Fund Transfer</span>
          </li>
          <li style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .4em; border-radius: .5em; display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;align-items:center;">
            <span style="color:grey;">Paid to</span>
            <span style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;">1234567r</span>
          </li>
          <li style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .4em; border-radius: .5em; display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;align-items:center;">
            <span style="color:grey;">Bank</span>
            <span style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;">Rdb Bank</span>
          </li>
          <li style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .4em; border-radius: .5em; display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;align-items:center;">
            <span style="color:grey;">Date of time</span>
            <span style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;">16-Aug-2021 11:50</span>
          </li>
          <li style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .4em; border-radius: .5em; display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;align-items:center;">
            <span style="color:grey;">Payment Status</span>
            <span style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;">Success</span>
          </li>
          <li style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .4em; border-radius: .5em; display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;align-items:center;">
            <span style="color:grey;">Reference number</span>
            <span style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;">32322</span>
          </li>
          <li style="border:1px solid #e3e3e3;padding: .4em; border-radius: .5em; display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;align-items:center;">
            <span style="color:grey;">Remark</span>
            <span style="color:#333;text-align:right;font-weight:600;">Monthly bonus</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p style='border-top:1px solid #e3e3e3;'></p>
        <p style='font-size:12px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;text-align:center;'><span style="color:#2E75B6;">Aug-2021 12:56 PM</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can I take the same output without using `Li`  ? only using html table?

Comment: @ Gamma hey mate, you can use div instead of `li` but regarding `table` you'll have to test how different browsers render flex properties applied to table elements.

Comment: If you do not mind, can you give me an sample code of how to do it using a table? please

Comment: @Gamma sorry mate must go out now, but you can make another question, so maybe I can answer later, cheers :)

Comment: sure I'll do so, thanks bro :)

Comment: @n I asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825228/how-can-i-use-curved-table-instead-of-li. please give me help when u have time. :) thanks again bro

Comment: I posted new question, but its closed by stackoverflow. can u please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825228/how-can-i-use-curved-table-instead-of-li